# Javascript Border and button line break question

Tags: javascript, html, button, border

I'm having a few issues with my javascript webpage. My first question is how to create a small border that wraps around a title? The bottom portion of my professor's sample webpage looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHXLp.png

The bottom portion of my webpage so far looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWMRg.png

I don't understand how to make that small border that circles around the "Shipping Method", "Shipping Address", and "Payment Details" titles.

Also for some reason the "
" tag on my "Complete Payment" button isn't placing my button on the next line for some reason. Here is my code so far, note though that it's incomplete so my functions and other features aren't ready yet, right now I'm just focusing purely on presentation. Thank you for your time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>YOUR NAME  Final Project Checkout</title>
    <link href="layout.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="guest-functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cart-functions.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload=function(){
    setGuest();
    updateCartTotal(); 
}



</script> 

</head>

<body>
<header><img src="90s-Gamers-Logo.png" width="798" height="82" alt="My Company"/></header>
<nav>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
<p>Choose a page to visit:<br>
  <select name="select" id="select" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="index.html">Home</option>
    <option value="shop.html">Shop</option>
    <option value="cart.html">Cart</option>
    <option value="checkout.html" selected="selected">Checkout</option>
  </select>
</p><br>

<p><b>Welcome Guest!</b></p>
<p>Enter your name:</p>
<input id="sign-in-text"><br>
<button onclick="setGuest()" id="sign-in-button">Sign-In</button><br><br>
<p>Your shopping cart is now</p>
<!--Need variable here-->
<p><b>empty!</b></p>
</form>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div id="divGuestArea">&nbsp;</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div id="divCartSummary">&nbsp;</div>

</nav>

<div id="main">
<h1>Checkout</h1>
<!--<p>This is where the transaction would take place so create a form here to take care of that final process as appropriate. Such form fields as contact info, shipping method, payment method, receipt, etc. Use HTML attributes wisely to help with validation and write JavaScript to validate any needed fields that are not sure to be validated by this HTML.</p>
<p>Connect your form to a "thankyou.html" page that you create so that after the form is submitted and found to be filled out properly, you thank them by name on "thankyou.html".</p>-->
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" summary="Table of Quantity, Description, Price, and Product Totals">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
                <td><b>Description</b></td>
                <td><b>Price</b></td>
                <td><b>Product Total</b></td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="text-align:right">
                <td>later</td>
                <td>later</td>
                <td>later</td>
                <td>later</td>
              </tr>
                <tr style="text-align:right">
                <td>later</td>
                <td>later</td>
                <td>later</td>
                <td>later</td>
              </tr>
                <tr style="text-align:right">
                <td colspan="3">Subtotal:</td>
                <td>later</td>
              </tr>
                <tr style="text-align:right">
                <td colspan="3">Tax:</td>
                <td>later</td>
              </tr>
                <tr style="text-align:right">
                <td colspan="3"><b>Grand total:</b></td>
                <td><b>later</b></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table><br>
<p>Display total amount</p>
<p>Shipping Method</p>
<p> <input type="radio" name="ShipType" id="standard" value="2">
                <label for="standard">Standard Shipping ($2)</label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="ShipType" id="2-day" value="5">
                <label for="2-day">2-Day Shipping ($5)</label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="ShipType" id="overnight" value="10">
                <label for="overnight">Overnight Shipping ($10)</label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <br>

<p>Shipping Address</p>
    Full Name:
    <input type="text" id="FullName" name="FullName">
    Street Address:
    <input type="text" id="StreetAddress" name="StreetAddress"><br><br>
    City:
    <input type="text" id="City" name="City">
    State/Province/Region:
    <input type="text" id="State" name="State"><br><br>
    ZIP:
    <input type="text" id="Zip" name="Zip">
    Country:
    <input type="text" id="Country" name="Country"><br><br>
    Phone Number:
    <input type="text" id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber"><br>

    <p>Payment Details</p>
    <select id="selPayment" name="selPayment" onChange="getSelectValue();">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">- Choose one -</option>
                    <option value="Visa">Visa Credit</option>
                    <option value="MasterCard">MasterCard Credit</option>
                    <option value="American Express">American Express Credit</option>
                    <option value="Debit Card">Debit Card</option>
                    <option value="Pay Pal">Paypal</option>
                </select> <br><br>

    Card #:
    <input type="text" id="CardNumber" name="CardNumber"><br><br>

    Expiration Month: 
    <select id="selMonth" name="selMonth" onChange="getSelectMonth();">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">- Choose one -</option>
                    <option value="January">January</option>
                    <option value="February">Febraury</option>
                    <option value="March">March</option>
                    <option value="April">April</option>
                    <option value="May">May</option>
                    <option value="June">June</option>
                    <option value="July">July</option>
                    <option value="August">August</option>
                    <option value="September">September</option>
                    <option value="October">October</option>
                    <option value="November">November</option>
                    <option value="December">December</option>
                </select> <br><br>
    Expiration Year:
    <select id="selYear" name="selYear" onChange="getSelectYear();">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">- Choose one -</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                    <option value="2021">2021</option>
                    <option value="2022">2022</option>
                    <option value="2023">2023</option>
                    <option value="2024">2024</option>


        <br><p>
        <input type="button" value="Complete Payment" 
               onclick="storeAndGo();">
    </p>
<footer>
Copyright 2020, 90's Gamers.
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's `<form><fieldset><legend>Title Here</legend><!-- other code here --></fieldset></form>`

Comment: By the way, block-level elements like `<div></div>` break lines. In this case it may be easier to just use a `<br />` tag after your button.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback everyone, I just decided to make a regular border using this code:

<style>
    p.groove {border-style: groove;}
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
</style>

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how to make that small border that circles around the "Shipping Method", "Shipping Address", and "Payment Details" titles.

**CSS**

```
border: 1px solid;
border-radius: 25px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div to your 3 sections, and you can set border to this.